# Nominatim Installation Error: Importing and Index OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap, installation, nominatim

I'm new to GIS and OSM. I've successfully installed OSM locally and now I want to add Nominatim to the mix. I've been following the installation instructions exactly from here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation.

I run into an error when I try to import and index the osm data. The command the guide uses to do this goes as follows:

```
   sudo ./utils/setup.php --osm-file <your planet file> --all [--osm2pgsql-cache 18000] 2>&1 | tee setup.log
```

I get a permissions error that I'm not sure how to fix and also it doesn't seem to like the cache specification. This is the error:

```
    tee: setup.log: Permission Denied
    setup.php: Unknown option '18000]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [] around --osm2pgsql-cache 18000

Drop the "| tee setup.log" part. (It just pipes the output to a file. And check your permissions)

Like this:

sudo ./utils/setup.php --osm-file isle-of-man-latest.osm.pbf --all --osm2pgsql-cache 18000

Always a good idea to test with a small file like this one: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/isle-of-man-latest.osm.pbf

Comment: I actually ended up getting it by not using the cache option entirely, and I fixed my permissions successfully. Thank you for getting back to me, hope your answer helps someone else.

Comment: Better use --osm2pgsql-cache on big osm files. Of course it has to fit your servers memory size

Answer (score 1):

Options in `[]` are optional. You can specify them but you don't have to. If you decide to use them then always strip the `[]`, i.e. just pass `--osm2pgsql-cache 18000` instead of `[--osm2pgsql-cache 18000]`.